# How to write the CRUD application form using JavaScript?

Tags: java, javascript, web-applications, crud

I need to create, edit and delete the data in mysql. I made the servlet program for CRUD operation. I want build the webpage which displays the Table and buttons for CRUD. How should i start up write my JavaScript.

Comment: You don't write user interfaces in JavaScript. That's HTML.

Comment: Maybe you should try to do a proof-of-concept, something simple that uses JavaScript, a button, sends a message to the server, the server parses it and saves something in BD. Then, when you are sure of how to do each part... think about a CRUD :)

Comment: @Delan Azabani If i can write using J-Query. what is J-Query actually. Please explain me.

Comment: jQuery is a JavaScript library that defines a bunch of functions to extend features and smooth out browser incompatibilities. I don't use it myself as I don't believe 'general' libraries are any good. If you can write it with JavaScript alone, why go and find a way to do it with jQuery? Read more: http://azabani.com/articles/dependence

Comment: @DelanAzabani why you link dead links. Bring the site up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should get your JavaScript to talk to your servlet that is performing the CRUD actions. So your button "Create" calls a create method in your servlet. A easy way to do this is to use the Direct Web Remoting (DWR) JavaScript library - check their tutorial.

Answer (score 1):

You should connect your javascript with a Web Service.